# Схожий или похожий?

Tags: выбор-слова, синонимы

В словаре Ефремова слово *схожий* определяется таким образом:

> **схожий:** Похожий на кого-л., что-л.

Есть ли какая-нибудь разница между словами *похожий* и *схожий*?

Comment: `схожий` - разговорный стиль, слово будет совершенно неуместно в официальном документе, и не очень часто употребляемое на мой взгляд.

Comment: @EugenePetrov , Вы не правы: [**пример**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD+%D0%9E+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9+%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%22+%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B9&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Comment: @Avtokod хм, действительно, хотя мне режет ухо и у [Ушакова](http://feb-web.ru/feb/ushakov/ush-abc/18/us461206.htm) отмечено как разговорное... в современном языке значит перестало таковым быть.

Comment: Но употребляется действительно намного реже - "схожий" - 3 миллиона ссылок в яндексе, "похожий" - 141 миллион.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слово "схожий" обычно употребляется в более узком значении. Например, "Иван схож с Петром" чаще всего означает, что у них есть какие-то общие черты характера, в то время как "Иван похож на Петра" в зависимости от контекста может значить и наличие общих черт характера, и сходство внешности.

Кроме того, употребление слова "похожий" в смысле отличном от физического сходства имеет оттенок неточности, разговорного стиля. Поэтому в качестве "книжного" (а также математического) термина в таких случаях употребляется слово "подобный".

Comment: А чем отличаются слова *схожий* и *подобный*? :)

Comment: @marmistrz Ну словари-то все три слова определяют как синонимы ;-) Особенность слова "подобный" в том, что оно в своем общеславянском корне означает также "пригодный, подходящий", т.е. нечто, что не просто похоже выглядит, но в некотором смысле может служить заменой.

Answer (score 1):

Похожий - имеет внешнее сходство

Схожий - имеет любое сходство, внешнее, внутреннее, по принципу действия и т.д.

Похожий = can be taken/mistaken for, reminds

Схожий = similar in essence or in certain features

Answer (score 0):

Схожий с Петром (с кем-чем? - дательный падеж).
Похожий на Петра (на кого-что? - Винительный падеж).
Схожий с кем-то.
Похожий на кого-то.